# get number of pages in search results

Tags: c#, html

I want to get number of pages at the bottom of any search page say google or bing
then i have to store the links of those pages for further navigation.

How can this be Done?

What approach should be used HTMLAGILITYPACK or HTTPWEBREQUEST or any other.It would be great if somebody demonstrate how to get tags with specific attributes i.e class name or ID

Google has nested like href has Span inside so we can have url from href but how to get span[image]text so that i can save it with name as page 1 url http:/blabla.com

Comment: Does the page you're calling display the number of pages?

Comment: if i would get a cent for any unclear question i read...

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: Classes are not ALL-CAPS

Comment: yes i did just for differentiation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the HTML Agility Pack:

```
var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
var elem = doc.GetElementById("someID");
var classedLinks = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
    .Where(e => e.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Contains("SomeClass"));
```

Comment: how can i use for above picture what should be placed at Descendants?

Answer (score 1):

Combined some code from SLaks and generated following code that gets navigation links at bottom of google

```
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.google.com.pk/search?rlz=1C1SKPL_enPK414PK414&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=asd");

 foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("table").Where(e => e.GetAttributeValue("id", "").Contains("nav")))
 {
     foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
     {
      foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("th|td"))
      {
          MessageBox.Show("cell: " + cell.InnerHtml);
      }
 }
```